# Disable Freepbx/Asterisk module upgrades

Tags: php, asterisk, centos6

I have customized and changed my Asterisk/Freepbx modules to suite my needs. But everything gets messed up during updates. How can I disable these updates? Is there something more elegant than changing the /etc/hosts, like an option to disable update checking. I'm using freepbx 2.11 on asterisk 11 in centos 6.5.

Comment: follow this path to solve the automatic update:
http://superuser.com/questions/267302/disable-automated-updates-and-notifications-in-kde-debian this might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a way. In the freepbx source code, i added a blank return statement to all the functions the checks for update. Now it works perfectly